# What is the fastest way to insert millions of rows into a SQL table in this case?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

The case scenario is the following.
Via C#, I am forced to call a stored procedure on an external server, which returns 50 million records every time it is called. Each record consists of several fields separated by commas, which I have to split and insert on a table of a database on another server. Since the records must be processed before being inserted, I think that using `SqlBulkCopy` is to be excluded, as it would write the data on the arrival table as they are, and not splitted. Saving all records on an array is prohibitive, as the RAM of the computer on which the `.exe` will run not sufficient for this purpose. Any ideas?

Comment: _I call a stored procedure on an external server, which returns 50 million records every time it is called._ I see a problem here.

Comment: Is it possible to make changes on the external server?

Comment: I know, but unfortunately I'm obliged to call this stored procedure, because it's the only way my company decided to pass me the data. It's not possible to make changes on the external server, not in a few days.

Comment: You forgot that those 50million rows also have delimited data, rather than a proper dataset, @Steve ;) I sense an XY problems here.

Comment: I would look into an ETL tool.  SSIS is meant for stuff like this.

Comment: If your company doesn't see the absurdity of these constraints and it is not willing to help you in resolving them then we have two possibilities here: 1) They don't care about your work, 2) They have serious problems on their IT department. In any case I suggest you to look around for a better employer,

Comment: Thanks, Steve, I'll definitely be looking around for a new job. Meanwhile, I'll try to convince their IT department to at least implement pagination for their SP.

Comment: See if you can use `SqlDataReader` to stream the results and process them one at a time.

Comment: You say that RAM is limited on the processing machine; there is enough, though, to hold the `DataTable` from the SP?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, unfortunately, no, there's enough RAM to hold around 1 million rows at maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The SqlBulkCopy class can stream a DataReader

- https://sqlbulkcopy-tutorial.net/enablestreaming
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.enablestreaming

Which mean you can create a custom DataReader that will encapsulate the DataReader in which the data come from.

Using a custom DataReader will let you process data row by row and make any formatting or other stuff your application require before the SqlBulkCopy copy the data from it.

By using `EnablesStreaming = true`, it will ensure that only a small amount of data are in memory.

> Are you suggesting me to implement the IDataReader interface?

Yes, since you need to process data before being inserted. And you need to stream so you cannot load everything in memory.

This is how in fact some of my libraries about Bulk Inserting work such as:

- https://bulk-operations.net/
- https://entityframework-extensions.net/

Under the hood, we use a custom IDataReader to access and process entities.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to implement the IDataReader interface?